# MarkLogic search in a particular file

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using below.

```
QueryManager queryMgr = dbClient.newQueryManager();     
StringQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newStringDefinition();       
// Some text eg. "test"
query.setCriteria(criteria);        
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();        
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

this does the search in all the docs.

How I can reuse this to make the search in a particular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd search a particular file.  But if you want to, try StructuredQueryBuilder.document.  Here's docs on using StructuredQueryBuilder: [1](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/java/searches#id_70572), [2](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html).